# Can't Load Data from Database using jquery ajax Asp.net webforms

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I'm gonna load tweet from database but it doesn't work please check where i'm doing mistake

**This is the div where i want to load tweets**

```
<div id="load_tweets">
</div>
```

**This is the setinterval method inside ready function**

```
setInterval(function () {
  $('#load_tweets').load("CS.aspx/fetch").fadeIn("slow");
  },1000);
```

**And This is fetch [webMethod]**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static DataTable fetch()
{
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=dbcomments;initial     catalog=CommentSystemUsingAjax;integrated security=true");
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tbl_tweet order by tweet_id desc", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
return dt;
}
```

**And i also tried this way**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string fetch(string tweet)
{
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=dbcomments;initial catalog=CommentSystemUsingAjax;integrated security=true");
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tbl_tweet order by tweet_id desc", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    tweet = dt.Rows[0]["tweet"].ToString();
}
return tweet;

}
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Change Web Method Return type from data table to string

```
[WebMethod]
public static string fetch()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connection string");
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);     
}
```

Now call static method using Ajax...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () 
    {
        FetchData();
    },1000);
});

function FetchData() {
    try {
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/Path/fetch",                    
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.d != "") {
                    var json_obj = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                    // get array of data in json_obj 
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: thnx but in fetchData() function control not entering into the $.ajax({......i debug the script it control directly jumped from $.ajax({ to the catch closing curly bracket .....now what should i have to do?

Comment: and where should i define the FetchData function either inside document.ready function or outside side document.ready function ?

Comment: keep FetchData function out side document.ready & keep debug inside  success i.e on your if condition

Comment: when i remove the if condition than it works but it returns data like this

[{"tweet_id":48,"tweet":""},{"tweet_id":47,"tweet":""},{"tweet_id":46,"tweet":""},{"tweet_id":45,"tweet":"sf"},{"tweet_id":44,"tweet":""},{"tweet_id":43,"tweet":"sad"},

Answer (score 0):

you should give the exact link of the page to the parameter of the load function

```
setInterval(function () {
  $('#load_tweets').load("/CS.aspx/fetch").fadeIn("slow");
},1000);
```

also back datatable you can't make me. you can just return the string. you can use json for this. you can get away with rendering ASP Net Control